# Disable sysrq f (OOM-killer) but leave other sysrq keys operational

Tags: out-of-memory, magic-sysrq

I was following a guide for automatically decrypting the hard drive on boot, using self-generated keys, and tpm2 variables, and near the end it makes this point that seems to make sense: https://blastrock.github.io/fde-tpm-sb.html#disable-the-magic-sysrq-key

> The magic SysRq key allows running some special kernel actions. The most dangerous ones are disabled by default, and you should keep them that way for maximum security.
>
> For example, one of them (f) will invoke the OOM-killer. This function could kill your lockscreen, giving full access to your desktop to a malicious user.

The problem is that I only found how to disable **all** sysrq keys, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/911522/how-can-i-enable-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-ubuntu-desktop or https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop, using something adding a `/etc/sysctl.d/90-sysrq.conf` file with this line:

```
kernel.sysrq=1
```

I would like if possible to be able to use all the other keys e.g. REISUB in case the system crashes, and only have the `F` key disabled.

I also found this article https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html, that mentions adding a bitmask like:

```
  2 =   0x2 - enable control of console logging level
  4 =   0x4 - enable control of keyboard (SAK, unraw)
  8 =   0x8 - enable debugging dumps of processes etc.
 16 =  0x10 - enable sync command
 32 =  0x20 - enable remount read-only
 64 =  0x40 - enable signalling of processes (term, kill, oom-kill)
128 =  0x80 - allow reboot/poweroff
256 = 0x100 - allow nicing of all RT tasks
```

but I don't understand how to have only sysrq-f disabled, and all other keys at their default value.

The current setup on my laptop (debian 12), is the following:

```bash
$ grep -IirF sysrq /etc/sysctl.*
/etc/sysctl.conf:# 0=disable, 1=enable all, >1 bitmask of sysrq functions
/etc/sysctl.conf:# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html
/etc/sysctl.conf:#kernel.sysrq=438

$ grep -IirF sysrq /etc/sysctl.d/*
/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:# 0=disable, 1=enable all, >1 bitmask of sysrq functions
/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html
/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:#kernel.sysrq=438
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absence of any process writing something to `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` (possibly via the `sysctl` command) at any point since boot (including in the initramfs)¹, the default value will be as configured at kernel compilation time.

You can find that out with:

```
$ grep -i sysrq "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_DEFAULT_ENABLE=0x01b6
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_SERIAL_SEQUENCE=""
```

Here for me (on Debian as well), it's enabled by default but with 0x01b6, that is 438 or 0b110110110 as the *mask*.

To check the current value:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
438
$ sysctl kernel.sysrq
kernel.sysrq = 438
```

That's 2|4|16|32|128|256 so:

```
  2 =   0x2 - enable control of console logging level
  4 =   0x4 - enable control of keyboard (SAK, unraw)
 16 =  0x10 - enable sync command
 32 =  0x20 - enable remount read-only
128 =  0x80 - allow reboot/poweroff
256 = 0x100 - allow nicing of all RT tasks
```

So all but:

```
  8 =   0x8 - enable debugging dumps of processes etc.
 64 =  0x40 - enable signalling of processes (term, kill, oom-kill)
```

You can check what bit of the bitmask allows which key in [`drivers/tty/sysrq.c` in the kernel source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?h=v6.5#n110).

[<kbd>f</kbd> is allowed by `SYSRQ_ENABLE_SIGNAL`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?h=v6.5#n408) with [value 0x0040](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sysrq.h?h=v6.5#n28), that is 64 above without surprise.

And that bit also controls <kbd>e</kbd> (end all tasks), <kbd>j</kbd> (thaw all frozen FS),<kbd>i</kbd> (killall tasks).

So it's not possible to enable all except <kbd>f</kbd>. The best you can do is enable all but <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd> by adding the 0x8 (SYSRQ_ENABLE_DUMP) bit which governs <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd> (also quite dangerous) to the default by writing 446 to `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`.

However, I would only deviate from the safer 438 default when debugging some kernel related issue where you lose shell access to the machine, or if no non-admin has physical access to a keyboard or serial line connected to the machine.

---

<sup>¹ also note the `sysrq_always_enabled` kernel command line parameter which bypasses all restrictions.</sup>